# "No point (in) doing something"- can "doing something" be "to do something?

Tags: phrase-usage

I know "No point (in) doing something" is correct, but I also see a lot of people using - no point "to do" something, so is it a situation that it is actually wrong but just people got used to use it? So can I say both are OK in real conversation?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where Google Books Ngrams can help us a lot. For those who don't know, this service lets you search for the frequency of words and phrases in the vast Google Books database. Its biggest limitation for ELL purposes is that the preferences of speakers do not always match the preferences of writers. That can be be a concern when the words or phrases under consideration are both in common use.

In our case, however, it is easy to see that **no point in verbing** is vastly more common than both **no point to verbing** and **no point to verb**. See [this plot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+point+in+doing%2Cno+point+doing%2Cno+point+to+doing%2Cno+point+to+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20point%20in%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20point%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20point%20to%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20point%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0), in which the verb is **do**. To be certain this verb choice is not an anomaly, [this plot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+point+in+saying%2Cno+point+saying%2Cno+point+to+saying%2Cno+point+to+say&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20point%20in%20saying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20point%20saying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20point%20to%20saying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20point%20to%20say%3B%2Cc0) tests the verb **say**. The results are virtually identical.

I emphatically recommend the use of **no point in verbing.** As both plots indicate, you may also say  **no point verbing**, but this structure is less common.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, “in” is more idiomatically correct, as least where I’m from (I speak AmE). I rarely ever use “No point to ____” as it sounds incorrect to me. It seems to be that the form “No point to ____” is grammatically erroneous but is used often enough for people to say it colloquially.

Comment: Can you edit that to give more details. As it stands it does not really help the OP with the underlying issue. Saying _where I am from_ is not super-helpful either since you could be anywhere as far as we know.